# How to change the background of another grid item while clicking on a Griditem in android

Tags: android, resources, calendar

i am creating a `calendar`, i have used `grid view to display the dates in that calendar`. Now i want to change the back ground of each grid item as user selects each one. Here the background changes as user clicks on a particular date but the previous items or date's background not rolling back to the original one? How can i achieve this?
For eg: if i click on the first grid view item, the item turns into blue color and when i click item 2 the color of item #2 becomes blue but 1st items remains with the same color, which i don't want to happen. how to change the 1st item color into default color.

```
if(cur_posn == 0){
   cur_posn = position;
   old_posn = position;
   v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calendar_tile_green);
} 
else {
   cur_posn = position;
   parent.getChildAt(old_posn).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calendar_tile_small);
   v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calendar_tile_green);                                                     
   old_posn = cur_posn;                                 
}
```

Comment: Which way you are changing the color? Please post your code.

Comment: new GridView(this).findViewWithTag(tag); you can set the tag as position. Save the selected item position and when the user click the other item simply access the previous item and change the background

Comment: Yes Triode, thats my idea but its not working here....

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want to do. Add this inside your adapter:

```
private int clickedChildPosition;

public void setClickedChildPosition(int newClickedChildPosition){
    this.clickedChildPosition=newClickedChildPosition;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
//Other things like setTag and getTag goes in here
    if(position==clickedChildPosition)
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calendar_tile_green);
    else
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calendar_tile_default);
}
```

And in your activity that uses that adapter call:

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            adapter.setClickedChildPosition(position);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

    });
```